# pythonによるai・機械学習・深層学習アプリのつくり方の教科書についての質問

Tags: python, anaconda

以下の本の346ページのAPIを呼び出すWebアプリを学習をしているのですが、コードを実行してもエラーメッセージが出てきて解決方がわからないので教えて欲しいです。
仮想環境はAnacondaを使ってPythonをやっています。

[PythonによるAI・機械学習・深層学習アプリのつくり方 (Amazon)](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4802612796/)

実行しているコード
https://github.com/yjyu12/uni-theme/tree/99e98995df940ed58299b6f74b56def258600daa/Theme

エラーが発生している場所(desk.py)

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/yamadaakira/Desktop/Theme/tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yamadaakira/Desktop/Theme/tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    models
NameError: name 'models' is not defined

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.062 seconds
```

エラーコード(tfidf.py)

```
Intel MKL WARNING: Support of Intel(R) Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2 (Intel(R) SSE4.2) enabled only processors has been deprecated. Intel oneAPI Math Kernel Library 2025.0 will require Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions (Intel(R) AVX) instructions.
Intel MKL WARNING: Support of Intel(R) Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2 (Intel(R) SSE4.2) enabled only processors has been deprecated. Intel oneAPI Math Kernel Library 2025.0 will require Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions (Intel(R) AVX) instructions.

Failed initializing MeCab. Please see the README for possible solutions:

    https://github.com/SamuraiT/mecab-python3#common-issues

If you are still having trouble, please file an issue here, and include the
ERROR DETAILS below:

    https://github.com/SamuraiT/mecab-python3/issues

issueを英語で書く必要はありません。

------------------- ERROR DETAILS ------------------------
arguments: -d /opt/homebrew/lib/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd
error message: [ifs] no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/lib/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd/dicrc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yamadaakira/Desktop/Theme/tfidf.py", line 7, in <module>
----------------------------------------------------------
    tagger = MeCab.Tagger(
  File "/Users/yamadaakira/opt/anaconda3/envs/mecab/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MeCab/__init__.py", line 124, in __init__
    super(Tagger, self).__init__(args)
RuntimeError

[Done] exited with code=1 in 7.969 seconds
```

Comment: 「エラーが発生している場所(desk.py)」とありますが、エラーメッセージには「tempCodeRunnerFile.py」とあります。貼り付けるメッセージを間違えていませんか？

Answer (score 0):

> no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/lib/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd/dicrc

とあるので、前提となるディレクトリが存在しないのではないですかね。

- 環境構築を失敗している
- コードに書くパスを間違った
- 環境が異なり、そもそもパスが違う。

このあたりかなと思いますがいかがでしょうか。